# LESS CSS inherit help

Tags: css, inheritance, less

im trying to streamline my css creation by using LESS. so far so good, however I came accross a problem, my code looks like so:

```
#content {

    h1 {
        font-size:20px;
    }

    h2 {
        font-size:10px;
    }
}
```

now i also want to apply `font-weight:normal;` to both the h1 and h2, how would i do this without having it in every rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
h1, h2
{
    font-weight:normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this

```
#content {

    h1 {
        font-size:20px;
    }

    h2 {
        font-size:10px;
    }
    h1, h2
    {
        font-weight:normal;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#content {
  font-weight:normal;
  h1 {
    font-size:20px;
  }

  h2 {
    font-size:10px;
  }
}
```

Sometimes it helps. Not in all situations actually.